# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: pandas

I want to find the number of rows of `clin` dataframe where the `OS_MONTHS` value is `<= 12.0`. The values in the `OS_MONTHS` are float.

This seems like a trivial question.

```
import pandas as pd

len(clin["OS_MONTHS"] <= 12.0)
```

Traceback:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Data type:

```
type(clin["OS_MONTHS"])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Dataframe

|  | SEX | KPS | A header | AGE | OS_MONTHS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 80 | 44 | 1 | 11.76 |
| 1 | 0 | 100 | 50 | 1 | 4.73 |
| 2 | 1 | 80 | 40 | 1 | 23.16 |
| 3 | 1 | 80 | 61 | 1 | 10.58 |
| 4 | 1 | 80 | 20 | 1 | 35.38 |

Answer (score 0):

```
clin["OS_MONTHS"].astype(float) <= 12.0
```

if you want to get length:

```
(clin["OS_MONTHS"].astype(float) <= 12.0).value_counts()
```

or

```
s = clin["OS_MONTHS"]
len(s[s.astype(float) <= 1.5])
```

get your data unique values: `unique()`, there are some values that are not in `float` format, and you must handle theme in a manner... for example:

```
clin["OS_MONTHS"][clin["OS_MONTHS"] != '[Not Available]']
```

Comment: `could not convert string to float: '[Not Available]'`

Comment: @melolili can you give me `.head()` of your data?

Comment: Sure, I pasted the dataframe in the question.

Comment: @melolili I edit my post, do it and comment result :)

Comment: After I convert to float using `clin["OS_MONTHS"][clin["OS_MONTHS"] != '[Not Available]'].astype(float)`, it still shows the same error.

Comment: @melolili exactly `could not convert string to float: '[Not Available]'`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244561/discussion-between-melolili-and-more).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
clin["OS_MONTHS"][~clin["OS_MONTHS"].str.replace('.','').str.isdigit()] = float('NaN')


# Then you can apply @MoRe's solution
clin["OS_MONTHS"].astype(float) <= 12.0
```

Comment: I want to count the number of rows that fit the criteria. When I apply len() to the second code, it threw an error.

Comment: You should apply sum to check all the true values not len. But len shouldn’t throw an error anyway. What’s the error?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `._convert(numeric=True)` . Unlike `.astype(float)`, this will transform to NaN all values it couldn't convert to floats.

So that would be:

```
len(clin[clin["OS_MONTHS"]._convert(numeric=True)<= 12.0])
```